# Motivation: Why look at norm subgroups in class field theory?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

**Background.** I'm reading about class field theory using a combination of Lang's Algebraic Number Theory and Tate's chapter in Cassels-Frohlich.

In Lang's chapter on ideles and adeles, he shows that any generalized ideal class group is a quotient of the idele class group. He then starts to look at norm subgroups.

In Cassels-Frohlich, Tate states that the "shift from powers to norms was decisive, and is due to Hilbert".

---

**Question.** I'm still left with the feeling that the introduction of "norm subgroups" is a bit unmotivated. Could someone perhaps point me in the direction of some motivating literature or give a concrete example (in the quadratic case or something) that shows how the transition to "thinking in norms" is natural?

Comment: Maybe Keith Conrad's notes on the history of class field theory are helpful, they are remarkably down-to-earth and motivates all quite well www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/cfthistory.pdf

Comment: I would say that Tate cohomology is an important tool in CFT, and for instance, the $H^0$ is constructed using norm subgroups. It is very natural because to consider the element $N_G = \sum_{g \in G} g$ acting on $A = L^{\times}$ where $G = \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is a finite group.